# What is the name of the Speed, Distance, Time relationship?

Tags: relations

Really simply, I'd like to know if there is a name used to describe the speed, distance & time relationship. i.e.

[image]

As this is basically the same relationship that applies to current, voltage and resitence in [Ohms Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law)

[image]

I'm sure there's another as well.

Comment: Yes, just as I once taught a daughter Ohm's law.

Comment: It is a coincidence. Velocity is defined as the rate of change of distance with respect to time. In contrast current, voltage and resistance are not related that way. Just because you have something being the product of two others does not mean that there is the same underlying reason. For example $P=IV$ and $W=QV$ and $E=hf$ and ...

Comment: surely that's an answer and not a comment? ;)

Comment: It's only one line and I didn't give any details, unless you want me to make it an answer..

Comment: @user21820: resistance is defined to be $\frac{dV}{dI}$, exactly like how velocity is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name is **the distance formula**.

> Distance travelled = rate $\times$ time travelled

[The formula Distance = Rate x Time expresses one of the most frequently used relations in algebra](https://web.archive.org/web/20171221031611/http://mathforum.org/dr.math/faq/faq.distance.html)

[Note the chart](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k-vTXwJObOI)

Comment: Although the distance formula also refers to the formula for the distance between two points in the plane (or in higher dimensions).

Answer (score 3):

You could say distance is jointly proportional to speed and time (the constant of proportionality is 1).  Or you could say speed is proportional to distance and inversely proportional to time.